# How does one test a new case with a saved machine-learning model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle, logistic-regression

Let's say I have a pickle file from a model and load it into python. How do I then test a new case to get a result whether the model says the case is likely to be one of the two output possibilities?

I trained a logistic regression model on the
[pima-indians-diabetes dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database)

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import pickle

names = ['preg', 'plas', 'pres', 'skin', 'test', 'mass', 'pedi', 'age', 'class']
dataframe = pd.read_csv('pima-indians-diabetes.csv', names=names)
array = dataframe.values
X = array[:,0:8]
Y = array[:,8]

test_size = 0.33
seed = 7
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=test_size, random_state=seed)
model = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
filename = 'linear_regression_final.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

after which I know I can load the model in later on with this:

`loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))`

(In my case I want to work with it in django but that shouldn't make a difference for my question)

Let's say I'd get another case with the necessary medical records without knowing if the person has or hasn't gotten diabetes. How can I test this new data against my model? And maybe as a follow-up question: Does the case need to have every single datapoint the model has or can I leave some datapoints out?

Comment: SO is not a substitute for reading tutorials. [ask]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you input data to the model (`X`) its shape has to be `num_samples x num_features`. In your case, it sounds like you want to get the prediction for a *single* sample. The shape of the test data should therefore be `1 x num_features`.

If some features are missing, you need to fill them in somehow, otherwise the model will raise an error. The model is expecting `num_features` columns per input sample.

You can get predictions from the trained model as follows:

```
test_prediction = loaded_model.predict(test_case)

test_probabilities = loaded_model.predict_proba(test_case)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I needed. So even for a single sample I need every datapoint that the model has been trained on and there is no way (other than filling them in) to omit values that I maybe don't have.